# How to do an if statement for if a cursor intersects with a label?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a maze game that is navigated using a mouse.

I have put labels onto a panel and use the panel leave event in order to reset the cursor back to the beginning.

There is this one label though, that it should not be resetting at, and so I'd like to make an exception for this one label. It's location is `300.400` and it's size is `1,10`.

I'm planning on making an if statement for if the cursor intersects but there is no feature like

```
Cursor.IntersectsWith()
```

so how would I be able to do this? I also tried to do

```
if cursor.position.x == 300
```

and something for `y` as well, but it turns out the position of `x` and `y` has nothing to do with the location of the label? I'm not sure how to do an `if` statement if the cursor is intersecting (or on) the label. Please help!

I'm aware I don't have code readily available, but the question is pretty clear!

Comment: What UI framework is this?  WinForms?  Silverlight?  WPF?  Something else?  In general you have to deal with different coordinate systems e.g. screen absolute, window absolute, relative to a particular control, etc.

Comment: uhm it's C#? So I guess WinForms? It's on a normal form.

Comment: Why not use the MouseEnter event on the label?

Comment: It's for a label that's like a FAKE finish, and the real finish is revealed. What would I do when it does mouse enter? Is there a way I can call to the mouse enter procedure and return a boolean into my panel leave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your question, there is a property called as `Name` for `Label`(s). 
I am assuming that you are using WinForms as you have mentioned nothing about the framework.
Instead of using `Loacation` as an identifier, use `Name` property of `Label` to make an 
exception.
Add this code inside the PanelLeave event handler:-

```
foreach(Label labels in LabelList)
{
  if(labels.Name!="exception-label-name-here")
      Reset() ; // function to reset the cursor position.
 // LabelList is a list containin all the `Label`(s) in your panel.
}
```

When you are adding `Label`(s) to your Panel, at that time add the `Label`(s) to a generic list which I have named as `LabelList`.

```
  private void MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     Label tmplbl = sender as Label ; 
     if(tmplbl.Name == "some-name-here.")
      // do something
     else if(tmplbl.Name == "some other name")
         // do something else.
     // in this way construct a if-else ladder.
  }
```

Comment: Then you can make use of `MouseEnter` event and then  loop through all the controls withing the Panel and check if its a label or not.

Comment: Can you show me how? I know how to do mouse enter, I have a mouse enter for lblFinish and all it does is set a boolean for true, and then theres a second label they have to reach to completely finish the maze. It's like a checkpoint to prove you're legit. If I were to allow the code to leave the panel when this boolean is true, after the checkpoint they wouldnt have to worry cause theyd go through every wall and thats not how the game should work.

Is there a way I can call to the mouse enter procedure and return a boolean into my panel leave?

Comment: Use the `MouseEnter` event on the labels not the panels

Comment: While I'm doing this, I noticed theres a small green error on the MouseEnter private void line thing. It says 'frmMaze.MouseEnter(object, System.EventArgs)' hides inherited member "System.Windows.Forms.Control.MouseEnter'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

It still lets me run the program with this error, but I thought I'd let you know

Comment: Yeah it's working so far, still doing a few changes but I'm happy :) thanks!  How do I get rid of that error notification I mentioned above though? ^^^^ The little notification to use new keyword or something.

Comment: I am not able to understand why that notification is coming, its a warning. You can accept the answer as it solved your problem, by clicking on the tick button next to my answer.